# Is it ok to skip "return None"?

Tags: python, function, return-value

I wonder if it is bad manner to skip `return None`, when it is not needed.

Example:

```
def foo1(x):
    if [some condition]:
        return Baz(x)
    else:
        return None

def foo2(x):
    if [some condition]:
        return Baz(x)

bar1 = foo1(x)
bar2 = foo2(x)
```

In both cases, when condition is false, function will return with `None`.

Comment: Note: I think that in the `foo1()` definition it is much cleaner to remove the `else:` branch and put `return None` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Like you said, `return None` is (almost) never needed.

But you should consider that the *intention* of your code is much clearer with an explicit `return None`. Remember: a piece of code also needs to be readable by human-beings, and being explicit usually helps.

Comment: Also helps to "comply" with `import this` :P

Comment: What about at the end of an `__init__` method? Since you can't `return None`, is it better to have `return` or nothing at all?

Comment: @dln385: You can `return None` in `__init__`, in fact that's what `return` does.

Comment: @dln385: I don't know if `__init__` is a *proper* constructor in Python, but it certainly works as one. So it should not return anything.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been thinking about another language like Java. In Python, you can indeed `return None` in `__init__`. In fact, if you try to return a value, it says `TypeError: __init__() should return None`

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: and @Nick I just got it, +1 to your comment :p

Comment: People parroting the "Zen of Python" make me constantly with for comment downvotes.  Implicit is better than explicit when it's clearer and avoids needless redundancy.

Comment: @dln385: Don't `return None` unless the None return value *itself* is meaningful.  The return value of `__init__` is *not* meaningful, so don't explicitly return None.  If you need to return from the middle of `__init__` just say `return`, and don't put an unnecessary `return` at the end of the function.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: so there's no need to be explicit, because there is no *intention* to return anything. I rest my case... :)

Comment: A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds. No need to increase the noise in your code just to be explicit, when anyone who knows anything about python can tell what would happens even when you don't add that return.

Comment: @EagerNoob I'm not saying to "consistently" add `return None` to every method - I'm just saying the intention of OP's *specific* code is made clearer by adding `return None`. Also, world is full of little minds, and I try to write code they could read as well.

Comment: @rsenna I pretty much agree with with you :), sorry if I wasn't clear ! I was disagreeing with people who were citing "explicit is better than implicit" here. `return None` might make sense where a function always returns a value, but for certain code paths no value is available. Here it would be more readable to be consistent with each code path ending with a `return` statement. Although just `return` seems sufficient and `return None` seems like overkill as Glenn pointed out.

Answer (score 27):

To expound on what others have said, I use a `return None` if the function is supposed to return a value.  In Python, all functions return a value, but often we write functions that only ever return None, because their return value is ignored.  In some languages, these would be called procedures.

So if a function is supposed to return a value, then I make sure all code paths have a return, and that the return has a value, even if it is None.

If a function "doesn't" return a value, that is, if it is never called by someone using its return value, then it's ok to end without a return, and if I need to return early, I use the bare form, `return`.

Comment: I would go further than this. I wish that Python functions returned a "No Value Returned" object by default, instead of None, and that Python raised an error if you ever tried to use the "No Value Returned" object (print it, assign to a variable, etc.). That would catch fairly common mistakes where people omit the `return` from a function. Then Python could also be changed to show `None` on the command line if you call a function that really does return `None` or remain silent if the function doesn't return anything. I got here by checking if there was a pep for this already, but no luck!

Answer (score 6):

Yes and No.

**In the simplest case, it is ok to skip** "return None" because it returns None in only single negative condition.

But if there are nested condition evaluation and multiple scenarios where a function could return None. I tend to include them as **visual documentation of the scenarios**.

[Editing: Based on comment below]

> return or return None

**I prefer "return None" to bare "return"** as It is explicit and later, no one will be in doubt if the return meant returning None or was it an error as something was missing.

Comment: Even with nesting you could just use `return` instead of `return None`. Sometimes it can be clearer to make the `None` explicit, but often people use `None` to indicate some sort of exceptional case, in which case raising a well-named exception would be better.

Comment: @adw : I agree with you. Some of these are style habits. I abhor using just "return" as if I had missed returning something. I prefer "return None" in such cases as I am explicit that this is what I wanted.

Comment: I personally do not use None for exceptional value but usually use it as place holder to indicate place for value. [] or () then indicate indefinite number of results and for some kind of functions they are better False-like value than return None (as None is not iterable)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you do not return any value from a Python function, it returns None. So, whether to explicitly return None is a stylistic decision.

Personally, I prefer to always return a value for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The more I think about it, the less I think the case you describe shows good practice. It forces the client to discriminate, so client code would almost always look like:

```
b = foo1(123)
if b is not None:
    ...
```

You couldn't even write:

```
if b:
    ...
```

since, if `Baz.__nonzero__` is overwritten, b could evaluate to False, even if it's not None. It would be better to have a `Null-Baz` instance (AKA [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)), e.g.:

```
class Baz(object):
    def some_method(self):
        """some action:"""
        ...
    ...

class BazNull(Baz):
    def some_method(self):
        """nothing happens here"""
    ...

Baz.Null = BazNull()

...

def foo1(x):
    if some_condition:
        return Baz(x)
    else:
        return Baz.Null

...

b = foo1(123)
b.some_method()
```

The point is: help the client (who might be yourself!) to keep [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) low. The fewer branches, the better.

Comment: Good point. But in some cases I'm forced to return None. Ie. in Django Middleware you will return None in most of your methods.

Comment: I downvoted this because even if the suggestion is valid in some cases, it is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo1(x):
    try:
        return Baz(x)
    except:
        raise ValueError('Incorrect value fo Bac')
```

or

```
def foo3(x):
    return Baz(x) if <condition> else False
```

I do not believe in half defined function, but this False can be usefull in search type failure pruning.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with a lot of the answers here.
Explicit is better than implicit but sometimes less is more when it comes to readability.

```
def get_cat():
    if cat_is_alive():
        return Cat()
# vs     

def get_cat():
    if cat_is_alive():
        return Cat()
    return None
```

In this particular example you have 2 extra lines that really provide no beneficial information since all functions return None by default.

Additionally explicitness of `return None` disappears even more with the usage of type hints:

```
def get_cat() -> Union[Cat, None]:
    if cat_is_alive():
        return Cat()
```

Including `return None` here is a double redundancy: None is returned by default and it's indicated explicitly in the type hint markup.

Imho avoid trailing `return None` they are absolutely pointless and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `return None` unnecessarily.

```py
def foo2(x):
    if [some condition]:
        return Baz(x)
```

is the more readable.

Since every single function in Python implicitly has `return None`; adding such a universal statement is unnecessary.