# Finding if any element in a list is in another list and return the first element found

Tags: python, python-2.7

It is easy to check if an element of a list is in another list using `any()`:

```
any(elem in list2 for elem in list1)
```

but is there anyway to idiomatic way to return the first element found?

I'd prefer a one-line solution rather than:

```
for elem in list1:
   if elem in list2:
       return elem
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists)

Comment: Do you want all matches, or the first match? Your example is the first match.

Comment: If you only want the first, it would be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118621/first-common-element-from-two-lists

Comment: @M4rtini That second link has [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16118989/1084416) (surprisingly) similar to [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35058744/1084416) using [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) but with much more detail and timings. I wonder whether the similarity is because it's idiomatic.

Comment: @PeterWood indeed, it would be the most logical way to do it, as a first try at least. Funny how that ends up happening on obvious duplicate worthy questions.

Comment: @PeterWood - i want the first match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is similar to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118621/first-common-element-from-two-lists/16118989#16118989) on [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118621/first-common-element-from-two-lists), where @jamylak goes into more detail of timing the results compared to other algorithms.

If you just want the first element that matches, use [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [14, 17, 9, 3, 8]
>>> next(element for element in a if element in b)
3
```

This isn't too efficient as it performs a linear search of `b` for each element. You could create a `set` from `b` which has better lookup performance:

```
>>> b_set = set(b)
>>> next(element for element in a if element in b_set)
```

If `next` doesn't find anything it raises an exception:

```
>>> a = [4, 5]
>>> next(element for element in a if element in b_set)
Traceback (most recent call last):
StopIteration
```

You can give it a default to return instead, e.g. `None`. However this changes the syntax of how the function parameters are parsed and you have to explicitly create a generator expression:

```
>>> None is next((element for element in a if element in b_set), None)
True
```

Comment: You may want to credit jamylak for the last part about return `None` if nothing is found. I assume you got inspired from him, since the edit happened after your comment about his answer in the duplicate?

Comment: I did get the idea to mention the possibility of failure to find the element after reading [their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16118989/1084416). However, they don't mention that themselves, it's implicit, and they don't expand upon it. I don't think I've copied anything from the answer. I use the idiom myself daily in my work, and didn't learn it from the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use sets: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

```
result = set(list1) & set(list2)
```

if you want to make it a conditional like any:

```
if (set(list1) & set(list2)):
    do something
```

Comment: add pop() to get one item as in the question: `result = (set(list1) & set(list2)).pop()`

Comment: This, of course, assume there is at least one common elemnt, or else a KeyError will raise.

Comment: Result is the result. if there are more elements in both lists, the result is more than one element . . .

Comment: With Python 3.11, calling `.pop()` on an empty set raises a `TypeError`, not a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1):

do like this:

`[e for e in a if e in b]`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, by using a filter when doing your list comprehension :

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = ['g', 'z', 'b', 'd', '33']
[elem for elem in list1 if elem in list2]
# ['b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[elem for elem in list1 if elem in list2]
```

Example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1, 10, 2, 20]

c = [elem for elem in list1 if elem in list2]
print(c)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def intersect(a, b):
  return list(set(a) & set(b))

print intersect(b1, b2)
```