# What's wrong with my code? Find the same value in two lists

Tags: python-3.x

Find the same value in two lists, e.g:

```
 A = [4,7,1,9]
 B = [5,8,7,2,4]
```

Below is my code, but I can't find what's wrong:

```
def samevalue(self, A, B):
    A = [4,7,1,9]
    B = [5,8,7,2,4]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
            if A[i] == B[j]:
                return A[i]
            else:
                return ValueError("there is no same value")
```

Comment: Can you format the code so I can have a better look at it?

Comment: I have put an answer for you. If it is helpful you can press the tick under the arrows by the answer to accept it. Hope it helps and welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Tata Fu, can you provide the exact output you want? Do you want the first match or the intersection of the lists?

Comment: Your function takes parameters `A` and `B` yet you ignore them and assign values to them. Why? Also, you define a parameter `self`, which is normally done when the function is a method belonging to a class definition. It serves no purpose here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First common element from two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118621/first-common-element-from-two-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function takes parameters `A` and `B` yet you ignore them and assign values to them. Why? Also, you define a parameter `self`, which is normally done when the function is a method belonging to a class definition. It serves no purpose here.

As been pointed out, you need to move `return ValueError("there is no same value")` out of the loop and execute it only after you have tested all values in `A` against all values in `B`:

```
def samevalue(A, B):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
            if A[i] == B[j]:
                return A[i]
    return ValueError("there is no same value")

print(samevalue([4,7,1,9], [5,8,7,2,4]))
```

Prints:

```
4
```

Or (more efficient):

```
def samevalue(A, B):
    for a in A:
        if a in B:
            return a
    return ValueError("there is no same value")
```

Or (most efficient for large lists):

```
def samevalue(A, B):
    seta = set(A)
    setb = set(B)
    setc = seta & setb
    if not setc:
        return ValueError("there is no same value")
    return setc.pop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `ValueError` after you have checked all the combinations and hence, the `return` statement should be outside of the for-loops.

```py
def samevalue(self, A, B):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
            if A[i] == B[j]:
                return A[i]
    return ValueError("there is no same value")
```

Comment: it should return only 1 match

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper, yeah it returns the first match if found

Comment: Exactly.. but my point is you need to store all matched element and then after return

Answer (score 0):

It should work perfectly with this. Make sure you return ValueError if there are no same values.

```
def samevalue(self, A, B):
    A = [4,7,1,9]
    B = [5,8,7,2,4]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
            if A[i] == B[j]:
                return A[i]
    return ValueError("there is no same value")
```

You could try this too

```
A = [4, 7, 1, 9]
B = [5, 8, 7, 2, 4]
for n in A:
    if n in B:
        print(n)
```

Comment: it should return only 1 match

Comment: That is what it does, hence why the return statement is there

Comment: if I not misread then what is this __find same value in 2 list__

Answer (score 0):

```
def samevalue(self, A, B):
    raiseerror = True
    A = [4,7,1,9]
    B = [5,8,7,2,4]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
            if A[i] == B[j]:
                yield A[i]
                raiseerror = False
    if raiseerror:
        return ValueError("there is no same value")
```

will be better, as it return all same value.
For improve:

```
A = [4, 7, 1, 9]
B = [5, 8, 7, 2, 4]
raise_error = True
for n in A:
    if n in B:
        print(n)
        raise_error = False
assert (not raise_error)
```

Comment: Neither "solution" does what the OP wants: The first solution does not return a value because it is a generator function (the OP presumably only wanted to return one value)  and the second solution raises an `AssertionError` rather than a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are returning from the `else` condition from inside the loops. So, the code will return a `ValueError` for the first mismatch, which is not what you want to do. Instead, you should let the loops finish so that you can be sure that you have checked each and every items in both the list. And if the loops have finished and no values are returned, this means that there were no matching values, which is when you raise and Error.

```
def samevalue():
    A = [4,7,1,9]
    B = [5,8,7,2,4]
    for a in A:
        for b in B:
            if a == b:
                return a

    return ValueError("there is no same value")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
#!/bin/python

#maybe you want this.
def samevalue_v1(A, B):
    C = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
            if A[i] == B[j]:
                C.append(A[i])
            else:
                continue
    return C

#and maybe a little performance improvements after the list sorted.
def samevalue_v2(A, B):
    C = []
    A = sorted(A)
    B = sorted(B)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
            if A[i] == B[j]:
                C.append(A[i])
            else:
                continue
    return C

#and maybe this is a better solution.
def samevalue_v3(A, B):
    C = []
    A = sorted(A)
    B = sorted(B)
    i = j = 0
    while i<len(A) and j<len(B):
        if A[i] < B[j]:
            i += 1
        elif A[i] > B[j]:
            j += 1
        else:
            C.append(A[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
    return C

A = [4, 7, 1, 9]
B = [5, 8, 7, 2, 4]
print(samevalue_v1(A, B))
print(samevalue_v2(A, B))
print(samevalue_v3(A, B))
```

Answer (score 0):

first why not iterate over each element on your lists? usin `for item in list`

but you can make simple, using filter function to find into the list and get you want:

```py
A = [4,7,1,9]
B = [5,8,7,2,4]

in_both = list(filter(lambda a: a in B, A))
```

it works for me.