# Loop through list until value is found then breaking?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,0,9,2]` that I want to loop through.

I want to create another list of dictionaries for every 3 elements until I reach a `0` element (i.e. the first dictionary will be `{'gold':1,'silver':2,'bronze':3}` and similarly for `4,5,6`). The loop will terminate since it reaches `0`.

So the resulting list would be: `[{'gold':1,'silver':2,'bronze':3},{'gold':4,'silver':5,'bronze':6}]`

Being new to Python and coming from a PHP background, how would I solve this leveraging functions like `zip` or `map` or would I have to resort to plain while loops?

Comment: Do you know that a zero would always occur on the first of a set of 3 elements? If it didn't should that triplet be included in the list?

Comment: No, a zero can occur anywhere, if a dictionary contains a zero it is discarded and the loop is terminated.

Comment: @VeraWang, what about the order of the keys?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham as shown.

Comment: @VeraWangm but your accepted answer has the numbers as keys?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it's a simple fix, I accepted based on the methodology used. Is this against SO rules? If so I'll change it.

Comment: @VeraWang, no,  I just want to make sure of the format you wanted. There are varying outputs posted as solutions

Comment: @VeraWang, should there always be three elements in the dict? What should `numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 6, 9, 0, 2]` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it should output only three dicts. The last dict `9, 0, 2` gets dropped since it contains a zero.

Comment: @VeraWang, it won't actually contain a zero using any of the answers but it will be shorter, you need to ignore the dict that has the wrong length, using modulo won't work.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, another case I've come up with is the list contains no zeros, it will terminate upon the last element. If the current dictionary has insufficient entries it is also discarded.

Comment: @VeraWang, that is no problem, checking the dict size will always work correctly, takewhile will also take all the list of there are no 0's so no matter what happens you will get the correct result. the important part is the length of the dict. You cannot use modulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import takewhile, islice


def groups(l, keys, i, n):
    # lambda x: x != 0 -> take elements until we encounter any 0
    tk = takewhile(lambda x: x != i, l)
    while True:
        d = dict(zip(keys, islice(tk, n)))
        if len(d) == n: # make sure we have n keys in the dict
            yield d
        else: 
            break

keys = ['gold', 'silver', 'bronze']
print(list(groups(l,keys,0,3)))
[{'bronze': 3, 'gold': 1, 'silver': 2}, {'bronze': 6, 'gold': 4, 'silver': 5}]
```

[takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the iterable as long as the predicate is true.

So we only take elements up to the first `i` we encounter,  `d = islice(tk,n)` takes a `n` length slice from our takewhile object using [islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), we then create a dict from the passed in keys, Creating the dict consumes `n` elements at a time so we move to the next three elements each time we call it. If the length of the takewhile object is not a multiple of of  `n` then we will have a dict at the end that is less than the size of `n` so `if len(d) == n:` will catch that and break the loop so the odd the length dict or an empty dict will terminate the while.

If you allow dicts with less than three keys:

```
from itertools import takewhile, islice,chain

def groups(l, keys, i, n):
    tk = takewhile(lambda x: x != i, l)
    return (dict(zip(keys, chain(islice(tk, n - 1),(i,)))) for i in tk)
```

Output:

```
In [5]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 6, 9, 0, 2]

In [6]: list(groups(l,['gold', 'silver', 'bronze'],0,3))
Out[6]: 
[{'bronze': 1, 'gold': 2, 'silver': 3},
 {'bronze': 4, 'gold': 5, 'silver': 6},
 {'bronze': 7, 'gold': 11, 'silver': 6},
 {'gold': 9}]
```

`islice(tk, n - 1)` takes a slice from our takewhile object len n - 1, we chain that and `i` so we get  `n` elements each time.

Or use filter to filter out the dict with less than 3 keys:

```
def groups(l, keys, i, n):
    tk = takewhile(lambda x: x != i, l)
    return filter(lambda x: len(x) == n, (dict(zip(keys, chain(islice(tk, n - 1),(i,)))) 
                                          for i in tk))
```

Which removes the shorter dict:

```
In [8]: list(groups(l,['gold', 'silver', 'bronze'],0,3))
Out[8]: 
[{'bronze': 1, 'gold': 2, 'silver': 3},
 {'bronze': 4, 'gold': 5, 'silver': 6},
 {'bronze': 7, 'gold': 11, 'silver': 6}]
```

This does the same as the previous we just filter any potential odd length dict from the end. For python2 use `itertools.ifilter` instead of filter.

Comment: in your first `groups` function, why doesn't it have a return statement?

Comment: @VeraWang, because we are yielding while the len of each dict is equal to `n` or else  we just break the loop because we have the a dict at the end that does not have three elements as the first 0 was at an index that ,was not a multiple of 3. You can iterate over the `groups(l,keys,0,3))` and get each dict on the fly, you don't have to call list and store the whole lists of dicts in memory, that is the advantage of using a generator.

Comment: If you want to have dicts that have `n` keys you need to check the length of each, the input in the second part of the answer will leave an odd length dict at the end

Comment: I see, strangely I've tried running your code: https://ideone.com/WzZGi5, it's resulting in an infinite loop both here and on my machine.

Comment: @VeraWang, I had the two parameters in the wrong order, it is fixed now.

Comment: accepting this as the answer because it is both readable and concise. It took me a little while to research the lamba/functional parts but it was worth it.

Comment: @VeraWang, yes sorry, I did not add any explanation, I just wanted to make sure we covered every case, the itertools lib is definitely worth  spending some time getting familiar with.

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import cycle

placings = cycle(['gold', 'silver', 'bronze'])
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,9,2]

def zipper(numbers, placings):

    d = {}

    for n, c in zip(numbers, placings):

        if n == 0:
            break

        d[n] = c

        if n % 3 == 0:
            yield d
            d = {}

print list(zipper(numbers, placings))
```

Comment: Nice one @John :) Good use of functional programming there!

Comment: @JamesMills I changed your edit from `return d` to `return None`, because there is the possibility that it would return a partially completed dictionary, and that would be bad behavior. After some [research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027586/is-it-ok-to-skip-return-none) I agree that functions should probably explicitly return something.

Comment: Very clean and readable. I should've learnt Python instead of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Easy! With a simple function, a data structure and simple iteration:

**Example:**

```
from collections import defaultdict


def f(xs, labels=("gold", "silver", "bronze")):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    n = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(xs):
        if x == 0:  # break if we see a 0
            return d

        d[labels[n]] += i  # update our counts

        # cycle through gold/silver/bronze (labels)
        n += 1
        if n % 3 == 0:
            n = 0

    return d


xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 9, 2]
d = f(xs)
print d
```

**Output:**

```
$ python foo.py 
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'bronze': 7, 'silver': 5, 'gold': 3})
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether to change my response to yield a sequence of dict(s) as per @John's response :) It seems that's the idea here!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to break the larger list into smaller lists of same size as of list `medals`, to make the `zip()` function work correctly, Also the position of `0` in the list should be at a position divisible by the length of the `medals` list, Otherwise the last list among the smaller lists would have lesser number of elements.

```
listOfDictionary = []
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,9,2]

ind = lst.index(0)   #Tells where to break the iteration loop.

medals = ["gold", "silver", "bronze"]

if ind%3==0:

    newlst = [lst[i: i+3]for i in xrange(0,ind,3)]
    #newlst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

    for lsst in newlst:
        listOfDictionary.append(dict(zip(medals, lsst)))


print listOfDictionary
>>> [{'bronze': 3, 'silver': 2, 'gold': 1}, {'bronze': 6, 'silver': 5, 'gold': 4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension in case of list and then using cycle

```
In [61]: mykeys
Out[61]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 9, 2]

In [63]: mykeys1=[i for i in mykeys[:-1 if 0 not in mykeys else mykeys.index(0)]]

In [64]: myvalues
Out[64]: ['gold', 'silver', 'bronze']

In [66]: myvalues1=cycle(myvalues)

In [67]: mydict=dict(zip(mykeys1,myvalues1))

In [68]: mydict
Out[68]: {1: 'gold', 2: 'silver', 3: 'bronze', 4: 'gold', 5: 'silver', 6: 'bronze'}
In [69]: [dict(mydict.items()[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(mykeys1),3)]
Out[69]: [{1: 'gold', 2: 'silver', 3: 'bronze'}, {4: 'gold', 5: 'silver', 6: 'bronze'}]
```

Comment: This creates a single dict

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham Thanks..I think question was modified..and i didn't see..thanks...btw your answer is the most elegant and i would have selected it as an anwser