# Some questions about the following code

Tags: python, return, user-defined-functions, python-3.6

I have the following questions about the following code:

1. What value does 0 hold in the second line? Is it something like 'true' or 'false'? Or a numerical value?
2. Are the return statements necessary in the user_even function? The code works without them but it seems that all user-defined functions have a return statement in them or am I wrong?

```py
def divisible(num1, num2):
    return num1 % num2 == 0

def user_even():
    num1 = int(input ("Choose a number: "))
    num2 = int(2)

    if divisible(num1, num2): 
        print ("It's even")
        return
    else:
        print ("it's odd")
        return
user_even()
```

Comment: 1. The value that `0` holds is, err, `0`. It's just the number zero. 2. No, they aren't, the function will implicitly `return None` and behave identically if they're removed.

Comment: Ok but if num1 = 10 and num2= 5, then 10/2=5. I don't understand what the zero represents in this instance because the answer isn't 0. How does 0 come into play to in terms of the answers being even or odd? This is so beyond my understanding that I don't even know if I'm explaining it properly. I'm a completed noob at coding.

Comment: Forget my previous comment, I think I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, it evaluates the statement and returns a Boolean (True or False) value. The 0 is 0.

```
return 5 % 5 == 0 # Remainder of 5/5 is 0 so that returns True
return 5 % 4 == 0 # Remainder of 5/4 is 1 so that returns False
```

For question 2, the return statements are not needed. A return statement should be used for variables or pieces of data that need to be returned from the function. In the code you provided, there is no data being returned so there is no need for the return statement.

Comment: Answer for question 2 is partially right but have some missing points. `return` statement is also used to exit a function.In the example above, there is no such condition but if you have a longer fuction where you want to stop execution of the function at some points, you simply place `return` statements so it will exit the fuction block without executing the further code lines.

but this is not the case in the above question.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1.) Return will be boolean because you used Comparator Operators (==)

2.) return statement is not necessary. Refer to this thread.
 [Is it ok to skip "return None"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027586/is-it-ok-to-skip-return-none)

Comment: Thank you mllduran. Just curious, is writing 'return' the same as 'return None'?

Comment: There is no difference. :) However, using 'return None' means that your function is meant to return a value for use later.